# How to create Sliding tabs inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-fragmentactivity

I have Created Five Tabs using FragmentActivity. Now I want to create three sliding tab layout inside one of those fragment. How can I achieve this? 
Please give any suggestion and tutorial will be great idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use View Pager inside one of the fragments

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/notice_titles"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```